# Fetch Streaming data from elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, apache-storm

We were processing realtime data, periodically data has been pushed into elasticsearch. I need to process those data whenever data pushed into elasticsearch, i need to get the data with help of python storm. Or anyother ways to achieve this solution. Can you give me some suggestion for fetching streaming data in python?

Comment: You could use Kafka to read from Python as well as push that data to Elasticsearch

Comment: Hey thanks. im using elasticsearch 6.3.1, is it support with python kafka? and can you please give me some links?

Comment: Python Kafka has nothing to do with Elasticsearch. I was saying if you put the streaming data into Kafka, then you can process it with Python as well as put it into ES as two independent processes